# How to refactor this function to get the correct error message in the catch block?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, try-catch

so I have this

```js
try {
  const user = await logUserInToApplication({ email, password })
  console.log(user, 'usr')
  await AsyncStorage.setItem('secureUid', user.user.uid)
  await dispatch(getCurrentUser(user.user.uid))
  setLoaded(true)
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e, 'e')
  setPassword('')
  setError(e.message)
  setLoaded(true)
}
```

but the problem is 2 things. firstly `user.user.uid` is ugly but secondly the main problem is that the `console.log(e)` is logging out `cannot read uid of defined` which makes sense but I want it to be the error from `logUserIntoApplication` if that fails

so I could change it to this

```
try {
   await logUserInToApplication({ email, password })
}
```

but then I need to get the value it returns me back so I can pass the uid into other functions, how do I do that?

Comment: const {user} = await logUserInToApplication({ email, password }); Try destructing. This will do some clean up

Comment: const myFunc = async () => = {
    try{
        const {user} = await ....
        return user.uid
    }
    catch(e){
        console.log(`Error ${e.messgae}`)
    }
}

myFunc will return uid

Comment: You should reject with the correct error in `logUserInToApplication`. Now you resolve it with some value that doesn't have a user.

Comment: Destructuring  won't give you an error you need, It would still give you an ```undefined``` error. You should throw error in ```kigUserInToApplication``` function or reject some error if you are using ```Promise```.

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
  const{ user } = await logUserInToApplication({ email, password })
  console.log(user, 'usr')
  if(user && user.id){
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('secureUid', user.uid)
    await dispatch(getCurrentUser(user.uid))
  } else {
   setError('set Error message here')
  }
  setLoaded(true)
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e, 'e')
  setError(e.message)
  setLoaded(true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `logUserInApplication` function is not throwing error;

```
try {
  const user = await logUserInToApplication({ email, password })
  console.log(user, 'usr')
     if(!user.user.uid) throw({message: "User id not found"})
  await AsyncStorage.setItem('secureUid', user.user.uid)
  await dispatch(getCurrentUser(user.user.uid))
  setLoaded(true)
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e, 'e')
  setPassword('')
  setError(e.message)
  setLoaded(true)
}
```

or you should throw some error or reject error in your `logUserInToApplication` function. Something like below:

```
const logUserInToApplication = async values => {
    try {
           const response = api.post(values);
           if(response.user.uid)
           return response.user;
           throw({ message: "User not found" })
    }
    catch(e) { throw(e); }

}
```